# Import third party js lib

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I would like to use a js-lib in my project which is on my local machine.

first of all I imported it in a simple basic index.html like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../sdk/frontendSDK-develop.js"></script>
```

and it worked fine.

Now I want to import it in my React App.

So I tried to import it the same way in my public/index.html like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../sdk/frontendSDK-develop.js"></script>
```

the file is loaded but it is not in the window object and in the console I have the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

I also tried to import it with

```
<script type="text/babel" src="../../sdk/frontendSDK-develop.js"></script>
```

No more error in the console but the script will also not be loaded.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> You can import external lib in the app.js file too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the path. It is not allowed to go outside of the dir where the index.html file is.
I had to move my .js file in to a folder under the index.html

So I had to change the import from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../sdk/frontendSDK-develop.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./sdk/frontendSDK-develop.js"></script>
```